# Task with path 'unzipJacocoAgent' not found in project ':app'

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

I've come across this error while trying to run my testCase using jacoco.

Upon calling ./gradlew jacocoTestReport in the root directory, I'm facing this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:testProductionDebugUnitTest'.

  > Task with path 'unzipJacocoAgent' not found in project ':app'.

Comment: Did you find a fix? I'm having the same problem currently...

Comment: no still having that issue @definera